# UK visa application after earlier refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I intended to travel to the UK for the PACES/MRCP exam back in May 2016. My visa was refused because of inadequate funds in my account and low salary. I was doing a fellowship in cardiology at that time and was earning only PKR 15000 (GBP 105) per month which was marked as insufficient balance.

Secondly, my mother had transferred around PKR 400,000 (GBP 2816) into my account as a gift from her account. I had with me my mother's account and transaction details, as well as an affidavit stating the amount was a gift.

Now 3 years have passed. I have completed my fellowship and I am working as a cardiologist in a government hospital with regular job and a salary of PKR 1,00,000 (GBP 588) per month. I have had this job for the last 2 years. I have a current running account of PKR 1650000 (GBP 9705) with my monthly expenses around PKR 20000 being paid from that account. I also have a car worth PKR 2.5 million (GBP 14000) in my name and I own some land worth PKR 50,00,000 (GBP 29411).

I recently passed the PACES/MRCP exams given in Doha, Qatar. I now intend to travel to London in July 2019 for a diploma-conferring ceremony at the Royal College of Physicians.

What should I do this time around so that my visa application doesn't get refused?

Comment: `please guide me so that this time around my visa doesnt get rejected.i shall be thankful` I will advise you to spend an hour or two a day for the next two or three weeks reading answered questions here about UK visa applications. Nobody can guide you so that your visa does not get rejected (that is in the consulars hands), but you can learn enough to avoid mistakes and give yourself a great probability.

Comment: thanks for reply.i do read about similar experiences...thats why i put mines over here...anything which i can improve..or any deficient thing which u people can correct abt my application

Comment: What is your reason to visit the UK? Although candidates can attend a ceremony, the RCP posts diplomas who don't attend (to those both within and outside of the UK, sent by special delivery). Do you wish to pursue further training or practice in the UK? If so, then it may be wise to have a more complete plan beyond attending a ceremony (e.g., applications in process, job interviews).

Comment: `I recently passed the PACES/MRCP exams given in Doha, Qatar. I now intend to travel to London in July 2019 for a diploma-conferring ceremony at the Royal College of Physicians.` It would be nice if you were visiting for additional purposes, say tourism, visit friends etc because like Giorgio wrote, the ceremony could be posted to you (the consular could use that excuse to deny your visa). Aside from that and from what you have written, it appears you have a solid profile. Physician with some assets. Salary is a bit low, but it is what it is. Finally being Pakistani seems a bit of a challenge

Comment: thanks.so you mean that if i go for diploma conferring ceremony it would be risky.should i skip it in order to save my future prospects of applying for visa when and if i apply for some job over there?

Comment: you are right in saying that they post diplomas to your address.my pure intention is to attend that prestigious diploma conferring ceremony but obviously not at the cost of rejection thereby decreasing my future prospects of going to uk for job..